# Why am getting following error after upgrade the eslint's version to `8.26.0'?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/comma-dangle': Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ecmaVersion')
Occurred while linting /home/code/app/src/index.tsx

[image]

My eslintrc.json

[image]

I have upgraded the eslint version to 8.26.0. I am getting the error during compilation. I am expecting to run my front-end server successfully.

Comment: How specifically were you running eslint? From the command line? Within VSCode via a plugin? What does the Output window say? Where did you find the Failed to Compile warning?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with you, my eslint version is 8.36, and the problem was solved by restarting vscode after lowering the version 7.x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately that's giving me `Could not resolve dependency:
peer eslint@">=8.27.0" from eslint-config-xo@0.43.1` and `Could not resolve dependency: peer eslint@">=8.0.0" from eslint-config-xo-typescript@0.57.0`. I realize I could likely back those up too, but at some point you're bending over backwards to support an error that's probably in `@typescript-eslint`.